# Visualforce Error : Map key true not found in map

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, repeat

[image]

*Visualforce Page*

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" controller="TaskRayController">
    <apex:form >
        <html>
            <head>
                <apex:slds />
            </head>
        </html>
        <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperMap[India]}" var="key" id="Repeat12">
                <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperMap[India][key]}" var="wrp" id="Repeat21">
                    <apex:input styleClass="slds-float--right" value="{!wrp.xc1}" style="width:112px;border-color: black;border-width: 1px;"></apex:input>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

*Apex Class*

```
public class TaskRayController {
    
    public TaskRayWrapper wrapper {get;set;}
    public Map<String,Map<String,TaskRayWrapper>> wrapperMap{get;set;}
    
    
    public TaskRayController() {
        wrapper = new TaskRayWrapper();
        wrapperMap = new Map<String,Map<String,TaskRayWrapper>>();
         map<string,TaskRayWrapper> tempMap = new map<string,TaskRayWrapper>();
        TaskRayWrapper wrpTemp = new TaskRayWrapper();
        
        tempMap.put('XC1', wrpTemp );
        wrapperMap.put('India',tempMap);
        
        List<TASKRAY__Project__c> records = [select id , Name,CreatedDate,Country__c  from TASKRAY__Project__c  
                                             order by CreatedDate desc limit 1];
        system.debug('currentRecord-->'+records);
    }
}
```

*Wrapper Class*

```
public class TaskRayWrapper {
    public string xc1{get;set;}
    public string xc1Comments {get;set;}
    
    public TaskRayWrapper(){
        xc1 = null;
        xc1Comments = null;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You have tried to use a symbol, India, in the expression instead of using a string. Try `value="{!wrapperMap['India']}"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax first is incorrect.

You have written `<apex:repeat value="{!wrapperMap[India]}" var="key" id="Repeat12">`
It should be `<apex:repeat value="{!wrapperMap['India']}" var="key" id="Repeat12">`
India with `'India'`. So that VF page recognizes it's a key from Map.

Rest I can see it working perfectly fine.

```
TaskRayWrapper wrpTemp = new TaskRayWrapper();
wrpTemp.xc1 = 'Hi';
wrpTemp.xc1Comments = 'Hi Comment';
tempMap.put('XC1', wrpTemp );
wrapperMap.put('India',tempMap);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works fine now. Just one more question what if I have 2 input and I want to catch multiple values in same variable ```XC1```, is it possible?

Comment: Then this map, `map<string,TaskRayWrapper> tempMap = new map<string,TaskRayWrapper>();` should change to `map<string,List<TaskRayWrapper> tempMap = new map<string,List<TaskRayWrapper>();`